# Macbook Pro Push Notification for Hotmail

Tags: ios, mac, iphone, apns

I received a notification from Apple stating that push notifications for Hotmail is getting revoked on April 8th.

Can someone help me reactivating this notification?

Comment: I guess "apply" should be changed to "Apple"? It's not clear to me what notification you received. Perhaps you can add a screenshot of the notification?

Answer (score 1):

Your Apple ID at some point was used to generate a certificate.

Either log in to your servers/service or MDM that use push services or start here:

- https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/